# Poner buttons dentro de un svg

Tags: html, bootstrap, svg

Tengo el siguiente diseño de un rectángulo en etiquetas `svg` en `html`, pero dentro de ella quisiera poner 2 botones circulares uno alado de otro, de que manera puedo hacerlo?

```html
  <div class="row">
                    <svg width="550" height="150">
                        <rect width="550" height="150" style="fill:rgb(200,209,208);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></rect>
                    </svg>
                </div>
```

Este es el boton circular que quisiera poner dentro

```css
.btn-circle.btn-xl { 
            width: 70px; 
            height: 70px; 
            padding: 10px 16px; 
            border-radius: 35px; 
            font-size: 12px; 
            text-align: center; 
        }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark btn-circle btn-xl">Black</button>
```

Comment: ¿Seguro necesitas un svg? Porque ese rectángulo se puede hacer con css. ¿Cuál versión de Bootstrap usas?

Comment: Si con svg, y uso bootstrap 4

Comment: Si necesitas utilizar un elemento HTML dentro de un elemento SVG lo puedes poner en un [<foreignObject>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/foreignObject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se puede hacer modificando el `row` para que tenga una posición relativa y los botones una absoluta. Luego opcionalmente (supuse que querrías los botones centrados) puedes usar en el `row` las clases `justify-content-center` para centrar los botones horizontalmente y `align-items-center` para centrarlos verticalmente.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

<style>
    .btn-circle.btn-xl {
        width: 70px;
        height: 70px;
        padding: 10px 16px;
        border-radius: 35px;
        font-size: 12px;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>

<div class="row position-relative justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <svg width="550" height="150">
        <rect width="550" height="150" style="fill:rgb(200,209,208);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)"></rect>
    </svg>
    <div class="position-absolute">
        <button type="button position-absolute" class="btn btn-dark btn-circle btn-xl">Black</button>
        <button type="button position-absolute" class="btn btn-dark btn-circle btn-xl">Black</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Me dice en el button que la position-absolute no es valido para el atributo type, y si le dejo solo el button si me salen los 2 botones pero debajo del rectangulo..

Comment: Si das click en el botón ejecutar de mi respuesta verás que funciona correctamente. Obviamente no puedes quitar la clase `position-absolute` a los botones ya que esta es la que los coloca dentro de la imagen svg. Supongo que el error lo llegas a tener al integrar este fragmento en tu página, pero para poder ayudarte en ello debo poder ver toda tu página.

Comment: El error que mencionas no lo conozco, pero `position-absolute` no debe estar en el atributo `type` del elemento, debe ir en el atributo `class`.